# Zero parameters in command definition

Tags: macros, conditionals

Let us say I want to define a command for typesetting (a+b)^2:

```
\newcommand{\sumsquare}[2]{\ensuremath{(#1+#2)^2}}
```

How can I modify it so that `\sumsquare{a}{0}` will produce a^2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest you change the syntax to `\sumsquare{a}{}`:

This can be coded either this way:

```
\newcommand{\sumsquare}[2]{%
   \ifx\\#2\\%
     \ensuremath{#1^2}}%
   \else
     \ensuremath{(#1+#2)^2}}%
   \fi
}
```

or:

```
\newcommand{\sumsquare}[2]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\tempvar{#2}%
   \ifx\tempvar\empty
     \endgroup
     \ensuremath{#1^2}}%
   \else
     \endgroup
     \ensuremath{(#1+#2)^2}}%
   \fi
}
```

If your really want `0` as the no-operant indicator you can define it like this:

```
\newcommand{\sumsquare}[2]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\tempvara{#2}%
   \def\tempvarb{0}%
   \ifx\tempvara\tempvarb
     \endgroup
     \ensuremath{#1^2}}%
   \else
     \endgroup
     \ensuremath{(#1+#2)^2}}%
   \fi
}
```

(I named the temporary variables this way to avoid `\makeatletter`. Normally `\@tempa` and `\@tempb` are used.)

### Explanation:

The `\ifx` command compares the next to tokens (e.g. macros, characters, ...) if the hold the same definition. In the last example the `0` and the `#2` are both defined to a macro each, which are then compared. This requires assignments and is therefore not expandable, i.e. doesn't work inside an `\edef`.

In the first code `\ifx\\#2\\` is used to test if `#2` is empty. If `#2` contains something, `\ifx` compares the first token in it with `\\`, which does not match as long `#2` doesn't start with `\\`. All other tokens are then simply taken as part of the *true* part and simply discarded with it.
If `\\` is a valid value for `#2` simply use some other macro like `\relax` or `\@nnil` instead.

However, if `#2` is empty the expression is reduced to `\ifx\\\\`, i.e. `\ifx` compares two `\\`, which are of course defined identical.

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick with the third solution, I find its usage more natural in my document.

Comment: @Anthony: Sure. I just thought I'm a little more general and explain the available options. This way it is also useful for other people which have the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpackages)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\sumsquare{mg}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\ensuremath{#1^2}}
    {\ensuremath{(#1+#2)^2}}
}
```

Comment: As I was reading this question I thought "aha, I'm sure an xparse solution would be elegant and simple." Then I thought "Ah, but I bet that pesky Joseph Wright will have beaten me to it..." And I was right.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done with an optional second argument, but it is not really shorter than typing it

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\sumsquare}[2]{\ensuremath{\ifx\relax#2\relax#1\else(#1+#2)\fi^2}}
\begin{document}

\sumsquare{a}{b} \sumsquare{a}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't this produce (a)^2 rather than a^2?

Comment: ah yes. I edited the code